# Laravel Pagination - Can't read parameter in url "/post/show/all?page=3" in production server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

we use laravel pagination and infinite-scroll when nextPageUrl called for getting next page data always return page one. in localhost work properly but when upload project in production server can't read parameter in url

```
all?page=3
```

and error is :

```
Undefined index: page
```

all Ajax request not working if there are parameter in path :

```
/state/{stateId}

/is/special/post/{id}/{value}
```

what extension or something else need to work this in linux server?

Comment: Can you share `web.php` and make sure your route has this wildcard `{page}`